Xcode Apple Silicon not comping ARM64 half precision neon instructions: Invalid operand for instruction
To date I have had no issue compiling and running complex ARM Neon assembly language routines in Xcode/CLANG, and the Apple M1 supposedly supports ARMv8.4.
But - when I try to use half precision with the following syntax:
" fadd v2.8h, v0.8h, v1.8h                  \n\t"
I get the compiler error "Invalid Operand for instruction".
Adding -mfpu=neon-fp16 to the compiler options didn't help.  Hoping it just uses a different syntax?
If anyone has achieved .8h instructions compiling in Xcode, I would be very grateful for any tips. Thank you.

I think I've solved the issue - or at least half of the issue - I can now get it to compile.  There were two key points:

The compiler flag to add is JUST -march=armv8.2-a+fp16 and nothing else.  I was trying too many things.

In XCode the way to add the flags is per C file.  Specifically...
Click on your project go to the Build Phases Tab.
Click on your target and you should see a list of the source files.
Click on each relevant source file and add -march=armv8.2-a+fp16


After I did this, it compiled.
I will add another comment if I find more info.

Running Xcode 15.3, it assembled with no problem.  Didn’t need your fix.
